# Checking if item has been indexed from an Array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have list or items to be added to Elasticsearch , but when i check the count i found that the items count is less in Elasticseach compare to the database .

So i created an array with all the ids in the database i want to know how can i compare it with elaticsearch

```
{
   "size": 100,
   "query": {
    "bool": { 
        "should": [
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": {
                        "terms": {
                            "ID": [
                                10400,
                                11024,
                                10401,
                                11026,
                                11053,
                                11061
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an aggregation query to list buckets for document IDs.
The following query will not include buckets for IDs that are not present in your index.
If you want buckets for IDs that are not in the index than you may want to use filter aggregation to write one filter query for each ID you are searching.

```
POST test_index/_search
    {
        "size": 0,
        "aggs":{
          "matching_values_field": {
             "filter": { 
                "terms" : { "id" : [
                10400,
                11024,
                10401,
                11026,
                11053,
                11061
              ]}
             },
             "aggs": {
                "myfield" : {
                    "terms" : { 
                        "field" : "id"
                    }                
                }
             }
          }
       }    
    }
```